# what's the theme name of intelij idea used in the official websites?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to know the name of  the theme name of intelij idea used in the official websites ,
it just like :
[image]

i have tried the theme of "darcola", but it seems not the same theme , it much darker than the theme which used in the official websites.

My intellij idea version : community 2017.2

Comment: It's "Darcula", colors could have changed a bit, your screenshot is from the older IntelliJ IDEA version.

Comment: yes, but darcula in my computer, it seems bad ...

Answer (score 1):

Theme differ version to version. You can try this material theme, if it supports your current version –
[Material Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui)